# Insert many-to-many relations in one transaction using Korma

Tags: sql, clojure, korma

I have 2 models with many-to-many relationship like the next:

```
(declare organisations)

(defentity users
  (many-to-many organisations :users_organisations
                {:lfk :user_id, :rfk :organisation_id}))

(defentity organisations
  (many-to-many users :users_organisations
                {:lfk :organisation_id, :rfk :user_id}))

(defentity users-organisations
  (table :users_organisations))
```

I want to insert rows into both models and make a relationship record in the same transaction

```
(transaction
  (let [usr (insert users (values {:email "john@mail.me"}))
        org (insert organisations (values {:title "My Co."}))]
    (insert users-organisation
            (values {:user_id (:id usr)
                     :organisation_id (:id org)}))))
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work this way. None of insertions into users or organisations work. Is it possible to do something like that in Korma?

What I try to achieve is something like the next Postgresql statement:

```
WITH new_user AS (
  INSERT INTO users (email)
  VALUES ('john@mail.me')
  RETURNING id
), new_org AS (
  INSERT INTO organisations (title)
  VALUES ('My Co.')
  RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO users_organisations (user_id, organisation_id)
VALUES ((SELECT id FROM new_user), (SELECT id FROM new_org))
RETURNING *;
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: And what is your error? I am using exactly the same code (except many-to-many definitions) in my application

Comment: @PetrMensik I have no errors, but queries inside `transaction`'s `let` are not executed at all.

Comment: And if you try to remove many-to-namy definitions from entities?

Comment: The same behaviour...